# Mootools resolve does not work

Tags: javascript, mootools

I don't have any clue why this resolve does not work ...
Can someone please help?

Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools-core-1.4.5-full-nocompat.js"></script>
        <script>alert($('div#root'));</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The alert function returns NULL instead of 'object htmldivobject'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just `$('root')` instead. In MooTools single `$` is <strike>equivalent</strike> [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766806/mootools-resolve-does-not-work/15767040?noredirect=1#comment22411206_15767040) to `document.getElementById` whilst `$$` is probably what you're looking for if you wanna use CSS-selectors.

See the difference here:

- [Single dollar $](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window:dollar)
- [Double dollar $$](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window:dollars)

Comment: it is LIKE `document.getElementById` - not at all equivalent. $ also sets up element storage, element uid and copies Element.prototype methods to actual element object in IE >= 8. using `document.getElementById` instead won't work

Comment: There is also `document.id` method, which is also `$`. You use it the same way.

Answer (score 1):

At the time the alert() stuff runs, the rest of the page hasn't been loaded/parsed/processed yet, so `#root` does not yet exist in the DOM. You need to use the domready() functionality to pause your code until the DOM's full loaded:

```
<script>
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    alert(blah blah blah);
});
</script>
```

Comment: that's what I thought in first place too, but it still does not work.

Comment: OP: you can also move your scripts at the bottom of the page - they will have access to any DOM nodes that precede them. also, don't do `$("dom#root")` - $ is like document.getElementById - `$('root')` will work. ids are unique anyway so no point in anchoring. multiple els is `$$()` which is where you need proper selector syntax. mootools is different to jquery :)

Comment: thats it, I would have ticked your answer as the right one but unfortunately you just made a comment :( Thx alot!